# Adding text to a label

Tags: asp.net, label

I am new to programming, and I am trying to build a web site with ASP.NET. I am trying to make a label that displays filters that are used after a user performs a search and specifies which filters to use. I am not sure how to display the filters being used in the label.

Comment: LabelName.Text = "filter, etc."; Is that what you are looking for??

Comment: So i can get it to say whatever i type in right? but how to i get it to display filters being used in a search?

Comment: Yes you can get it to say whatever you want. What kind of search are you doing ? Can you provide your current code ?

Comment: So making it display text isnt my problem, what i cant figure out is how to make is display a specific thing thats already part of the code, if that makes sense. Also, im not sure how to display the code without it getting jarbled up

Comment: Like, how to make the labels display the filters that are part of the search after the user has specified which ones they want from a drop down box

Comment: Or basically just anything besides that i manually type in myself

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary variable with type string. for e.g :

```
Dim tempFilterText as String = ""
tempFilterText &= "You filter the data with criteria : Country " & dropdownlistCountry.selectedvalue
tempFilterText &= " and City " & dropdownlistCity.selectedvalue
tempFilterText &= " and ZipCode " & txtZipCode.Value
```

then you can assign your label like this

```
labelCriteria.Text = tempFilterText
```

I hope that's what you are looking for

Comment: That is along the lines of what im trying to do, yes. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that, could you please mark as the answer if this match with your solution.